# DateFormatter wrong date formatting for midday hours

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, ios10

I've noticed strange behavior of DateFormatter in my code:

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
    let dateAsString = "2016-12-28T12:36:14.000Z"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)

    //formattedDate equals "2016-12-28 00:36:14 UTC"
```

DateFormatter's behavior is quite strange, because the problem appears **ONLY** when the date has hour "12" (year, month and day don't really matter here). In fact, for all dates in a period of 12:00:00 - 12:59:59 the formatted date is shifted 12 hours back, to midnight.

For any other date the formatter works good, let's say:

```
dateAsString = "2016-12-28T11:59:41.000Z"
...
formattedDate = "2016-12-28 11:59:41 UTC"
```

and so on...

What could be a reason of this strange behavior? Is there any gentle way (without checking if date's hour equals to 12 and then adding 12 hours to formatted date) to fix it?

The code is written in Swift 3.0 and is running iOS 10+. The problem appears in all iOS 10+ versions.

Thanks!

Comment: ISO8601 date strings are in 24-hour format so it's `HH`

Comment: Small change, big result! `HH` solved the issue! Thanks!

Comment: @vadian put it as answer to mark this is resolved